# RestAdapter Retrofit(2.0.2) cannot resolve symbol android studio

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am working on a project to pick data from soundcloud but I can't seem to resolve this problem. Please help me.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
}
```

and this is my code

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Config.API_URL).build();
        SCService scService = restAdapter.create(SCService.class);
        scService.getRecentTracks(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()), new Callback<List<Track>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Track>> call, Response<List<Track>> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "First track title: " + tracks.get(0).getTitle());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Track>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error);
            }
        });
```

Please help!

Comment: Please tell us exactly _what_ does not work.

Comment: The above code is for retrofit 1.9, please refer http://square.github.io/retrofit/ for retrofit 2.0 request

Comment: By the way, you will want to remove this line in your Gradle and the gson jar file from the libs folder.  `compile files('libs/gson-2.6.2.jar')` since you've compile Gson below it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RestAdapter is depreciated in Retrofit 2,thats why you are getting this error.You are using Retrofit 2.In Retrofit 2 RestAdapter is replaced with Retrofit,So you need to use Retrofit,
here is a simple example,

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

Please refer the docs,for more details [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Comment: Does that mean I replace the whole code with it? Am so new to this.

Comment: Please read the documentation this and make the changes according to your need.This is just a sample